# Excel Pivot Table filters values changing on source update

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table

In our BI infrastructure we're using Excel's pivot tables to expose the data in an Analysis Service instance (the cube), and thus far we have nothing to complain about.

Excel "reports" can be defined containing pre-selected dimensions as rows, columns and filters, for example we can set the **Time** dimension as a column slicer, or the **Country** dimension as a filter slicer. This allows the users to access this pre-defined report with the slicers already in place where they just have to select there own values to slice with if needs be.

However, even tough this is working perfectly the issue emerges when we try to actually pre-define specific values in a filter slicer. These values are getting "randomly" changed after a few days without any particular pattern from what we can observe. (Note that the cube i.e. the data source is being updated daily)

For example, we want to create a report were the users would have the data already filtered by the countries Italy and France upon opening it. So we created a report where we have the **Country** as a filter slicer and the countries Italy and France set as specific slicers under the Country filter.

Now the problem is that this report would maintain it's structure and selected filter values for just a few days, after which Italy may get de-selected and Germany would now be selected, or only France is maintained as a slicer. And again, we can't seem to observe any particular pattern in these changes, neither the time it's taking to "lose its format", or the filter values being selected to filter with.

Furthermore, note that even tough the underlying data source is changing daily, the pre-selected values are always there and never deleted, i.e. Italy and France in this case, would always be available in the data source. In fact you could still select them in the report, even tough they are no longer selected by default.

Anyone can help us understand why this is occurring and what can be done to go around it?

**EDIT**
Just realized that the slicer which values keeps changing every once in a while, is a column in another table. For example the Country Italy is in reality a column in a table City and therefore can be found in multiple records such as Rome, Milan etc., and then is exposed as a dimension in SSAS.

Comment: What's the key for the Country dimension or attribute? Is it an identity column and do you truncate and rebuild dimensions daily? Wondering if key 2 means France one day and Germany the next in the DW?

Comment: Hmm no really now, the ID (a guid) is never changed since in this case the same ID from the live is used.

Answer (score 0):

In PivotTable Options/Data there is an option called: "Number of items to retain per field" which default is set to automatic.

I believe this might be what causes it to work at random, and then suddenly change. Try changing it to 'max'.

Comment: Have tried that already, but the option is disabled and set to Automatic. From what I can understand this is because we're using SSAS as a data source.

Correction
The particular option you mentioned is not there. The only similar option available is "Retain items deleted from the data source" which is disabled and set to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Install BIDS Helper and open Your source code in Visual Studio. Then run [Dimension Health Check](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/DimensionHealthCheck/) on the City dimension. I expect it will show some attribute relationship uniqueness issues. Fix the keys or attribute relationships and your problem should be fixed. If you need help knowing how to fix it post a screenshot of Dimension Health Check here.